# Java String.split not saving to Array

Tags: java, split

Hi i'm having trouble saving my string.split value to an array my array is empty after i use the following code.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = in.nextLine();
        in.close();
        if(input.matches("^[0-6][.][0-6]$"))
        {
            b = false;
            String[] coordinates = input.split(".");
            int c1 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0]);
            int c2 = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1]);
            playingfield.PlayTurn(c1, c2);
```

it tells me coordinates[0] and [1] are null.

Everything up to that point works and the Regex is correct to As i can just print the String there and it works fine

Comment: What did you input?

Comment: @paper1111 my input was 1.1

Comment: As an aside, I strongly recommend *not* calling `in.close()`.

Comment: No, your regular expression isn’t correct either. There too you need to escape the dot with `\\`, or it will match strings with any character between the two digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
String[] coordinates = input.split(".");
```

with

```
String[] coordinates = input.split("\\.");
```

Split takes a regular expression as a parameter. `.` matches anything (meaning the whole String), not the dot character as you expect.

Comment: This gives me an invalid escape sequence error.

Comment: You need 2 backslashes (I've edited, the formatter did not like it the first time).

Comment: worked perfectly thank you!